# How do I view the json string returned from web method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying understand how to view the json data returned from a web method on an asp.net page. The method works, but I am not sure how to view the data. Ultimately I am binding this data to a world map. Here is the codeblocks

```
        $( document ).ready(GetCountryData);
        function GetCountryData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test.aspx/PopulateCountries",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function(response) {
                    alert("Failure " + response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert("Succuess " + response.d);
        }
```

and  this is the web method

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function PopulateCountries() As String
    Dim temp As String = Nothing
    Dim Product As New ProductsBLLWithSProcs
    Dim ds As New CountryBLLWithSProcs
    Dim dt As LocationsDataTable = ds.GetCountriesWithProducts
    Try
        temp = ToJSONRepresentation(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return temp
End Function
Public Shared Function ToJSONRepresentation(dt As LocationsDataTable) As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim jw As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(New StringWriter(sb))
    For Each row As LocationsRow In dt.Rows

        jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        jw.WriteStartObject()
        jw.WritePropertyName("id")
        jw.WriteValue(row.locCountry)
        jw.WritePropertyName("name")
        jw.WriteValue(row.locName)
        jw.WritePropertyName("quantity")
        jw.WriteValue(row.Quantity)
        jw.WriteEndObject()
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

How do I view the results using either the console.log method or on the alert method. Thanks for any pointers

Comment: 1) press f12 to open your Developer Tools. 2) go to the Network section. 3) run your code, and watch the Ajax call appear in the list of network requests. 4) click on the Ajax call and go to the Response section to view the raw response

Comment: Alternatively if you prefer you could add the following line to your OnSuccess function: `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` and you'll see the data appear in the Console in the Developer Tools

Comment: Thank you for that information. I will be trying it out